# Differences of Sequence of verbs

Tags: tense-agreement

> 1-I will tell him I will go to the cinema.

Here, the event "going cinema" is later than telling. We use future "will" here.

> 2-I will call you before I arrive.

Although arriving is later than calling, in contrast to the first sentence, we use present simple here. What is the reason of it?

Comment: I think the simplest answer for #2 is a) because that's the way English is, and b) the "present simple" doesn't always refer to something literally happening at the present time; it can also refer to a general phenomenon.  For example, "I eat fish" - it doesn't mean I am doing it right now, it just means that it is a thing that happens.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you could change the tense of the verb and the sentence could still make perfect sense. For example, "I will tell him I went to the cinema." At some time in the future, I will tell him that I went to the cinema in the past. There is no problem with the idea of telling someone in the future about something that I did in the past. Likewise, "Tomorrow I will tell him that I am going to the cinema now." Again, there is no problem with telling someone in the future about something I am doing in the present.

In the second example, the word "before" indicates a time sequence. So you can't use verb tenses that contradict that time sequence and have the sentence still make sense. "I will call you tomorrow before I arrived yesterday" makes no sense. You can say, "I will call you before I will arrive", but the extra "will" isn't really necessary because the sequence is already spelled out by the "before".

Answer (score 1):

The sentence *I will tell him (that) I will go to the cinema* is an example of *reported speech*. *I will go to the cinema* is a reported clause.

The main verb in reported clauses can be in any tense. For example:

- I will tell him I *went* to the cinema. (past)
- I will tell him I *plan* to go the cinema. (present)

In this case, the cinema visit is in the future, so a future construction is used:

I will tell him I *will go* the cinema. (future with *will*)

The second sentence contains a *temporal clause*, namely *before I arrive*. As Swan states in *Practical English Usage* (p99) in the section called *present tense with future meaning*:

> With *before*, we use a present tense if the meaning is future.
>
> - I'll  telephone you before I come. (not ... <strike>before I will come</strike>.)